# Retrieving Country list from stripe library in andorid

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I want to get country list supported by stripe in android.
After googling I found [this link](https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#list_country_specs) to get the country list

i am using

```
 Map<String, Object> countryspecParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    countryspecParams.put("limit", "3");

    CountrySpec.list(countryspecParams);
```

above code but android IDE showing me ***CountrySpec*** can not resolve

*Adding this in gradle file*

> ```
> implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.1.2'
> ```

please help me.

Comment: IMO, you forgot to add a library for this in your dependencies. Please check once

Comment: already using this     implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.1.2'

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the log message in Logcat in Android Studio ?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma the keyword CountrySpec can not resolved

Comment: Does it return Country Code?

Comment: @UmangBurman no , it is showing CountrySpec can not resolve

Comment: I got that, I'm asking generally like "What does it return, does it return country code?"

Comment: @UmangBurman it will return JSON data , for more you can check link , https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#list_country_specs

Answer (score 1):

`CountrySpec` is available in the java library. You are using the Android mobile library. [Here](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android) are the docs for that one. It doesn't seem to have this country list endpoint.

You can click on the curl tab and you'll see the url which you need to call : https://api.stripe.com/v1/country_specs?limit=3. And you need to add the api key in a header (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY')

Comment: Thank you for your reply , so how can i get country list at application side ?

Answer (score 0):

No such info found in the api, but there are not so many countries they support at the moment.

check this out:

https://support.stripe.com/questions/what-countries-does-stripe-support

Answer (score 0):

This endpoint is not included in the Stripe-Android library because it leverages the Secret API Key, which you should not include in a mobile App.  Meaning, if you want this information, you would need to proxy the request through your own backend and execute the request with one of our other client libraries that can use the Secret API Key to get at this information.

Hope that helps!